# iOS universal links not working for new bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

Currently universal links are working for our production app identifier(com.dubizzle.dubizzlehorizontal), so we've introduced a new bundle identifier for beta environments in app. Surprisingly the deeplinks are not working after configuring this new bundle identifer(com.dubizzle.beta)

enable associated domains against new bundle identifier on developer.apple.com

update apple app site association file as below for new beta identifier & the changes appeared in updated association file

```
{
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
      "ZBPP83795K.com.dubizzle.dealerapp"
    ]
  },
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "ZBPP83795K.com.dubizzle.DubizzleHorizontal",
        "paths": [
          "/m/ar/property-for-rent/short-term-daily/villahouse/*",
          "/m/ar/property-for-rent/short-term-daily/apartmentflat/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "appID": "ZBPP83795K.com.dubizzle.beta",
        "paths": [
          "/m/ar/property-for-rent/short-term-daily/villahouse/*",
          "/m/ar/property-for-rent/short-term-daily/apartmentflat/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        "appIDs": ["3AS69H23V9.com.bayut.bayutpro"],
        "components": [
          {"/": "/profolio/*"},
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

update associated domains in xcode capabilities

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfY73.png)

tried uninstalling app & restarting phone & updating version number

After trying these things, i was expecting that the deeplinks will open in my app or safari should show the option of open in app. Please suggest if there is anything that i'm missing, it feels like new bundle identifier isn't working. Is there anything where i need to configure this new identifer to get deeplinks working

Comment: so i tried enabling associated domains development in device developer settings and it somehow updated the association file and deeplinks started working for newly added beta identifier, also i added developer mode in associated domains for beta